# c++ проблема с std::vector

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```
vector<char> str;
int a;
while(cin >> a)
    str.push_back(a);
for(vector<char>::const_iterator i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i;
```

По моей задумке, должна быть выведена введенная строка

Comment: а если, допустим, у нас есть объект  `vector< vector<char> > text;`  то можем ли мы, допустим, рассматривать `text[i].size`?

Answer (score 3):

Вы вводите не символы, как вам кажется, а числа. Так что если вы наберете что-то отличное от целого числа, то, соответственно...

```
vector<char> str;
char a;
while(cin >> a)
    str.push_back(a);
for(vector<char>::const_iterator i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i;
```

Вот так будет работать, только ввод вам надо будет завершать нажатием Ctrl-Z в Windows (в Linux Ctrl-D, кажется... не помню точно) - раз вы проверяете состояние потока `cin`.

Но почему бы вам не работать со строками `string`?

Comment: vector подключен, завершение Ctrl-D на Линуксе не помогает, строка не выводится. Я думаю, может проблемы в самом qt

Comment: Все, вопрос исчерпан. Я сплю на ходу. Спасибо!

Comment: А вот такой еще вопрос, возможно ли избежать ключевой комбинации для проверки потока cin, используя enter при завершении ввода?

Comment: @Freddy: Ну так сами ручками и проверяйте введенное значение `a` и выходите из цикла при обнаружении `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить ожидаемый результат, вы должны вводить по отдельной цифре, как, например, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0, и преобразовывать эти целочисленные значения в коды символов цифр, как показано ниже в демонстрационной программе

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{

    std::vector<char> str;

    int a;

    while ( std::cin >> a ) str.push_back( a + '0' );

    for ( char c : str ) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Если вы введете не отдельную цифру, е некоторое число, то результат уже будет не предсказуем.

Есть стандартная функция `std::to_string`, которая переводит число в объект типа `std::string`.

Например, вы могли бы написать

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> str;
    int x;

    while (std::cin >> x)
    {
        std::string tmp = std::to_string(x);

        if (!str.empty()) str.push_back(' ');

        str.insert(str.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    }

    for (char c : str) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int a;
> ```

```
char a;
```

> ```
> ... str.begin(); i != str.end(); ++i
> ```

```
... str.cbegin(); i != str.cend(); ++i
//      ^__________________^--------------- константный
```

Comment: Есть перегрузки `begin` `end`, возвращающие константные итераторы. В этом примере именно они и вызываются

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Вызывается не константный итератор. Но его можно сравнивать с константным итератором.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, перегрузок на основе возвращаемого значения [почти](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586066/178988) не бывает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, их вообще не бывает. Никаких _почти_. В ответе по ссылке нет никакой перегрузки.

Comment: @ixSci, я знаю, просто так написал :) В общем-то, в данном случае та же штука - возвращаемый тип приводится к другому.